# Is there a data structure similar to a list in Haskell, which allows the replacement of elements in O(1)?

Tags: haskell, data-structures

so far I've only found vector and sequences, but neither of those could replace an element of a list in O(1). Such data structure would of course violate the immutable character of Haskells structures, but maybe there still exist some dirty implementation?
Every feedback is welcom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mutable, random-access array/vector with high performance in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892065/mutable-random-access-array-vector-with-high-performance-in-haskell)

Comment: `Data.Vector` is a good place to look first. There's a mutable version, too.

Answer (score 7):

As you suggest yourself – I'm also pretty sure a safe, purely-functional update in *O*(1) is not possible. What is possible is in *O*(log *n*) with a tree-like implementation; for instance, instead of `[a]` you could use `Data.Map.Map Int a` with a contiguous region of indices. Also, it is possible to do a *batch update* of *k* ≤ *n* elements in a list or vector, in only *O*(*n*) instead of the *O*(*k·n*) it would take to manually insert them one-by-one. Check out [`//`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.1.2/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:-47--47-).

If none of that is fast enough for you, then yes, you will need to go into the dark realm of mutability. Fortunately, Haskell offers a good safety armour and flashlight for such journeys: the [`ST` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html). The way it works is, you wrap the entire region where you need to do mutable updates in [`runST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html#v:runST). Inside that region, you use [`MVector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.1.2/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html)s, which support *O*(1) [mutable element updates](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.1.2/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html#g:10), much like you could in an imperative language. But thanks to a type-system trick, `runST` ensures that all these side-effects stay confined to within the local scope.

Comment: re "safe, purely-functional update in O(1)", when it's essentially *uniquely used* like [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Accumulating_Array), in the tail call to a tail recursive worker function, why should it be illegal for `a // xs` to be compiled so that it does take `O(|xs|)` time? I realize it's a pretty narrow special case for a compiler / interpreter  to handle, but still.... (maybe laziness makes it harder...)

Comment: @WillNess well, it's a special case that lots of people would find super useful. I'd be surprised if nobody had tried to implement this; maybe vector+GHC _will_ actually fuse that to something _O_ (|`xs`|) in some cases. Just, in those cases where the rewrite is obvious, you could probably as well get to the goal with some other purely-functional tools from the vector library, that are guaranteed to have good complexity. In the more complicated examples, I wouldn't trust the rewrite rules, and code that runs not just slower but with _worse complexity_ without full optimisation... meh.